# Table cell constraints breaking on row insert

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I have a UICollectionView in a table view cell. I've put a few constraints on the cell to make the UICollectionView a square. A button in the cell above will insert another view, effectively pushing the UICollectionView cell to move down to make room for the new cell. When I do this, the constraints on the UICollectionView seem to be ignored.

[The code can be found here.](https://github.com/bqmackay/BMMoreDetails)

Why would the constraints decide to be ignored when I insert a row? What should I call to keep the constraints? I've tried re-adding the constraints and calling layoutIfNeeded(), but that didn't add them back.

Edit: Some images to show what is going on

Before:
[image]

After:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem came from mixing frames with constraints. In the GameboardCell class, I overrode layoutSubviews to include setting the gameboard's frame. Later, I set the constraints programatically. By removing the frame, the constraints hold up.

```
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        //gameboard?.frame = self.contentView.bounds
    }
```

Lesson of the day: Don't mix frames with constraints.